# wav oggenc html audio -> why it deosn't work in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, audio, ffmpeg, ogg

I have very strange issue. I want to play ogg files on firefox using audio tag. But when I try to run this audio, firebug reporting this error:

```
Media resource http://127.0.0.1/packhorse/src/sounds/558143.ogg could not be decoded.


xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

jquery-1.8.2.js (wiersz 8416)
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

I creating this ogg files from wav files generated by timidity++ using oggenc command.
When I'm trying to open this file directly in firefox, I get black screen with grey box and the following error:

```
Video can't be played becouse the file is corrupt.
```

But I don't want to play video - it's the audio file.

I was thought that is some mime issue as long as I realized that on chrome everything work correctly. Have you know what can couse that problems?

You can download audio file which I want to play on firefox from here:

```
http://193.17.184.23/892643.ogg
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we have the HTML tags you used to embedd your ogg file  pls ?

Also, try this :

```
<audio preload="auto" controls="controls">
<source src="media/song.ogg" type="application/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: I also try that but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the  ".htaccess" file and check if you have the following:

```
AddType audio/ogg oga ogg
AddType video/ogg ogv
```

If you don't add it in. That should fix your audio problems and also presuming it will also be causing problems with video then should fix that too.

Comment: I use nginx so it does't work. But I've already added this mimes to /etc/nginx/mime.types but it hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is trying a different converter.

Comment: http://gnu1.software.informer.com/download-gnu-ogg-to-wav-converter/ There's plenty here that all should be legit.